# Creating ticks in a matplotlib heatmap based on range of values

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am creating a heatmap in matplotlib where on the x and y axis is some parameter of a measurement and the color represents the value of the measurement. Matplotlib automatically gives the axes ticks based on the index of the value. For example if on the x axis I am measuring at 50 different values the ticks will be from 0 to 50. However the real value of this parameter is for example from -30 to 80 and I would like matplotlib to create the ticks based on this minimum and maximum.

I have tried using set_xticks but this requires the positions of the ticks as well as their labels. I am thinking that I should be able to just give matplotlib a min of -34 and max of 67 and have it create nice looking ticks placed at the proper positions but I haven't been able to find how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging in examples on the matplotlib website I found this option in `imshow` called `extent` in which you can replace the default zero-based coordinates with your own values for the min and max of both axes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't pyplot.xlim() or pyplot.figure.set_xlim() work in this case? Just say something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlim(-30,80)
plt.ylim(0,100) #Or whatever
```

As far as I know the set_xticks function is too sophisticated for this. With that one you can specify what to put as your tick labels etc. For example if you want to associate a numerical series with a series of letters. For example:

```
x = [-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8]
labels = ['K2','K4','K6','K8','M0','M2','M4','M6','M8']
plt.xticks(x, labels)
```

Is one I used personally to translate integers into stellar spectral types (which is relevant, since I'm an astronomer ;p).

Hope this helps.

`

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However the set_xlim function will just change the part of the figure you are looking at, still using the pixel coordinates [like this](http://imgur.com/OaNpJ6x). I posted an answer to my own question with the solution that I found.

Comment: Hm, I see your solution in the other post, but I don't know what the difference is between that and set_xlim. I always use xlim to constrain my axes, so what exactly is the difference between your first plot and the one you provided in the answer? I'm curious, because I thought I understood your question, but I'm not sure anymore :p

Comment: Imshow takes a matrix of data and assigns values to the axes based on the dimensions of the matrix. I wanted the axes to show the actual parameters that were used to obtain the value which can be done with the extent option. However I am now already using the pcolor function which takes two arrays for the axes and then a matrix for the data values